# How is a function approximated by Fourier analysis?

Tags: field-theory, computational-physics, fourier-transform, mathematics, approximations

Quantum mechanics and QFT use extensively Fourier analysis.

When trying to approximate a periodic function by Fourier series (say a rectangular wave), it is possible to increase the number of terms until the approximation seems good enough for our ends.

But Fourier analysis aims to approximate also functions limited to a finite range. The underlying idea is to use the destructive interference of the harmonic functions to get zero out of that range.

Suppose I know $f(p)$, and want to evaluate numerically, (because the integrand is not analytically solvable), the Fourier transform to get $f(x)$.

I can proceed as in Fourier series, choosing an interval, splitting $f(p)$ in a series of coefficients that multiplies the exponentials, and adding all the parts.

But when I go that way, what I get is always a periodic function, what I know it is not the case.

Is there other way to have progressively better estimates as it happens in Fourier series (or Taylor expansions)?

Comment: Is there anything wrong with saying your function is the Fourier series multiplied by a function that is zero outside your specified range?

Comment: @Jahan Claes If I know f(p), the range where it is meanignful is also known. But it does't mean that the same range is valid to f(x). In principle I don't know how f(x) spreads to define a range.

Comment: Why can't you just extrapolate your function smoothly in both directions to make it periodic? I don't see the point in making it zero outside the original range.

Comment: @D. Halsey That is the point of Fourier analysis. It is possible to describe a wave pulse (or package), not only periodic waves.

Answer (score 2):

Periodic functions $f(t)$ (with a time period $T$)
can be approximated by a [Fourier *series*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series),
i.e. by summing harmonic oscillations with the *discrete* frequencies
$0, \frac{2\pi}{T}, 2\frac{2\pi}{T}, 3\frac{2\pi}{T}, \ldots$ .
$$f(t)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} F_n e^{in\frac{2\pi}{T}t}$$

But, as you already noticed, with a Fourier series you
cannot build *aperiodic* functions
(e.g. functions limited to a finite range).
For approximating such functions you need a [Fourier *integral*](http://www.math.toronto.edu/courses/apm346h1/20151/L15.html),
i.e. summing harmonic oscillations with *all*
frequencies from $0$ to $\infty$.
$$f(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}F(\omega)e^{i\omega t}\ d\omega$$

---

#### Example 1: Periodic function $\to$ discrete spectrum

As an example for $f(t)$ let's choose the [rectangular
wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_wave) (with period $T$) extending from $t=-\infty$ to $t=+\infty$.
[image: periodic function]
$f(t)$ is a perfectly periodic function, and therefore
can be decomposed into a Fourier series.
Its spectrum (the Fourier coefficients $F_n$) look like this:
[image: discrete spectrum]

#### Eaxample 2: Aperiodic function $\to$ continuous spectrum

Now as a second example for $f(t)$ let's choose the rectangular
wave (again with period $T$) restricted to a certain range.
Outside this range we define $f(t)=0$.
[image: aperiodic (but nearly periodic) function]
Obviously this function is quite similar to the first example.
Therefore we expect its spectrum to be somehow similar to the
spectrum of the first example.

Because $f(t)$ is aperiodic, it cannot be decomposed into a
Fourier series. But it can be decomposed into a Fourier integral.
Its Fourier spectrum (the function $F(\omega)$) looks like this:
[image: continuous (but nearly discrete) spectrum]
<sub>(Function plots created with [FooPlot](http://fooplot.com))</sub>

This spectrum is continuous, but still quite similar to the
discrete spectrum of the first eample. It has some pronounced
peaks (at the same frequencies as in the first example).
But there is also some spectral intensity outside of these peaks.